# Finding curve length and simplifying messy integrals

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the curve from A to B.

Curve $ y = 2/3*x^{2/3}$

I completed the first couple of steps. I'm not sure if I did them correctly. I arrive at $\int_1^8(\sqrt{1+16/81*x^{-2/3}})$dx

I'm not sure how to simply the integral. How may I do it?

Comment: Based on that curve and your interval, this integral is indeed correct. WA [indicates](http://po.st/2NU7VU) that it has an elementary indefinite integral, so this should be tractable (if perhaps not simple to obtain)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than treating $y$ as a function of $x$, it is instructive to parametrize the curve as $(x(t),y(t))=(t^3,2t^2/3)$ with $1\leq t\leq 2$. Then $s'(t)^2=x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2=(3t^2)^2+(4t/3)^2$ and simplifying $s'(t)$ allows us to write the arc length as  $$\text{arc length} = \int_1^2 s'(t)\,dt = \int_1^2 t \sqrt{9t^2+16/9}\,dt.$$ This can be transformed back to your original integral by the substitution $x=t^3$; in this form, however, a useful $u$-substitution becomes more obvious. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm not sure how to simply the integral. How may I do it?*

Integration by parts, followed by the substitution $t=1+\dfrac{16}{81}\cdot x^{-2/3}$.